# What have I done? pointer to pointer to pointer to double?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For some reason I think I have allRates is x*y*z length pointer to doubles and rates is essentially a 3dimensional array. But I can't recall exactly how this works.

```
// Allocate 3D Rate Array  
 double *allRates = malloc( x*y*z*sizeof(double) );
  if (!allRates) exit(1);
 double ***rates = malloc( x*sizeof(double **) );
  if (!rates) exit(1);

 for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
  rates[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(double *));
// Check rates[i] allocation?
  for(j=0; j<y; j++) {
   rates[i][j] = allRates + (i*y*z) + (j*z);
  }
 }
```

It runs properly... I'm just working on documentation and haven't worked on this part of the code since March.

Comment: One good reason why you should comment your code - it's not *just* for the benefit of other people...

Comment: Often in this situation, it is best to ask one's self what the _idea_ behind the code is. Then the code, messy as it is, makes better sense. Because you know the idea, you have the best chance to solve this problem. Let the time wasted in figuring this out again be a lesson to you regarding the utility of documentation.

Comment: You know I did comment all of the mathematical part of the code... I just forgot about these obscure (to me) data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Allocate 3D Rate Array  
 double *allRates = malloc( x*y*z*sizeof(double) );
  if (!allRates) exit(1);
```

allocates a block of memory large enough to hold `x*y*z` values of type `double` (if the dimensions are small enough; if the mathematical result of the product isn't representable as a `size_t`, it allocates the remainder of that modulo `SIZE_MAX + 1`).

```
 double ***rates = malloc( x*sizeof(double **) );
  if (!rates) exit(1);
```

allocates a block of memory large enough to hold `x` values of type `double**` (again, if `x` is small enough). Those are used as the indices for the first dimension.

```
 for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
  rates[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(double *));
// Check rates[i] allocation?
```

Checking the allocation is definitely advisable. If nothing fails, each `rates[i]` is made to point to a block of memory large enough to hold `y` pointers to `double`.

```
  for(j=0; j<y; j++) {
   rates[i][j] = allRates + (i*y*z) + (j*z);
  }
 }
```

Each of the `double*`s `rates[i][j]` is made to point into the block allocated to `allRates`, at an offset of `i*(y*z) + j*z` elements, `i` times the size of an `y×z`-plane plus `j` times the length of a `z`-element row, so that `rates[i][j]` points to the first element of row `j` in plane `i`.

If C99 is available, or `y` and `z` are compile-time constants, that would be simpler achieved by allocating

```
double (*rates)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof *rates);
```

with fewer indirections when addressing.

Comment: Thank you. I was really unsure about what the structure of these objects were.

Comment: Actually x and y are both runtime options. z is variable determined earlier in the program.